# RibbonButton with Text?

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

does anybody know if it is possible to replace the largeimage of the RibbunButton with plain text?
I have a Button with a short text - I could make a picture of the text, but that would be a little bit awkward.

```
<RibbonButton  x:Name="cmdTableSinglMean" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action cmdTableSingl($view)]"  Label="SinglMean" ToolTip="Tabellen Typ: Singl"/>
```

Comment: Just don't include the `largeimage`? `xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/ribbon"` then do; `<my:RibbonButton Name="cmdTableSinglMean" Width="auto" Height="auto" Label="SinglMean" />` Hope that helps.

Comment: @gregory.bmclub I tried that, but that looks not so good - the text is rendered in its full width. That looks totally weird.

Comment: You could create a `ribbongroup` like so; `<ribbon:RibbonGroup x:Name="test" Header="SignleMean"> <my:RibbonButton Name="cmdTableSinglMean" Width="auto" Height="auto" Label="SinglMean" /> </ribbon:RibbonGroup>` That way you can group that item and specify how large the text you want etc.